# Insert breakline after textbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to insert a breakline (`<br />`) after every textbox on click of a button using the below code :

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="text1" /><b>This is test</b>
<br />
<button>New line</button>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
$("#text1").append("<br />");
});
});
```

I am getting the following error in the console

**Message: Object doesn't support this property or method**

Please let me know how I can achieve this.

Comment: You want to append the `br` element after the `input` or after the `b` element? Or do you mean a line-break within the `input` itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use after() instead of append.

http://api.jquery.com/after/

http://jsfiddle.net/66ERc/

Comment: No problem - append is used for things like appending a LI to a UL, or a row to a table, or appending some information onto a current element that can contain something (input can not contain tags, but a DIV could).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
var txt = $("text1");
txt.val( txt.val() + "\n");
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(){
   $("#text1").after("<br />");
  });
});
```